# If $f(n) = o(g(n))$ then $f(n) + g(n) = \theta(g(n))$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm fairly certain that in this case  $f(n) + g(n) =\Theta(g(n))$ is true, but I'm having trouble to proof this. Can someone please put me in the right direction?

Comment: Would you be okay with a calculus-based proof rather than an explicit algebraic one? Then, $$\left|\frac{f(n)+g(n)}{g(n)}\right|=\left|1+\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right|\to 1\in (0,\infty)~~\text{ as }n\to\infty$$ which shows $f+g\in\Theta(g(n))$ (we used $f(n)=o(g(n))$ in the form $\left|\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n) \in o(g(n))\Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$$
 $$f(n) + g(n) \in \Theta(g(n)) \Longleftrightarrow \exists c:\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n) + g(n)}{g(n)} = c$$

Can you prove $\exists c:\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n) + g(n)}{g(n)} = c$ given $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$?